# Windows 10 iot Raspberry Pi 2 Tcp Connection c++

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have write server/client app. between raspberry pi2 and windows PC.(Raspi is server). If I placed both server and client program on raspberry pi2 then it works, but when client is run from windows pc then it I couldn't connect , got error timeout(10060). I am simply connecting pc and pi2 through a switch, firewall of my PC is disabled.
My sample code as same as windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889(v=vs.85).aspx

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you know what error you get from the `connect` call, then you're not using the code in the MSDN example, because the example doesn't print the error code on connection failure. If you have changed that part, what other parts might you have changed without telling us?

Comment: I just added a printf to log result. and also I have changed sending byte streams. But As you see problem is about connection. I haven't changed any code about connection flow. Also it work if both are on raspi.

Comment: Can you connect from the Windows box to the RaspPi by other means (e.g. SSH, HTTP, Ping)? I.e., is it a *code* problem or a *network* problem?

Comment: I can connect via powershell also connect with http webserver and looked device current status.

Comment: And the server program isn't busy doing something else? A tmeout error like that you will typically get if the server program has correctly created the listening socket and bound it and called `listen`, but doesn't call `accept`. Maybe add some extra logging to the server program to see that it actually calls `accept` and is not doing anything else.

Comment: I have tried as you said. Server code comes to listen and passed succesffuly then waits at accept function.

Comment: Another detail about my problem : I have connect to device and run netstat -a and I saw that My connection local adress is 0.0.0.0:27015 Foreign adress ; 0.0.0.0 State : Listening . This is meaningful for someone  ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution. We need to add a firewall rule to Windows 10 iot.

like:
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80